# How to watch the output of ls with wildcards in bash, displaying the output in columns

Tags: bash, arguments, watch, ls

Using bash, I am trying to write a command (for my bashrc) that updates the output of ls every 2 s, displaying the output in columns (rather than one item per line). I have a command that works, but when I include an (optional) argument to only list certain files (eg. `wls *.log`), the wildcard is evaluated before being passed to ls, so I get the output `aaa.log` rather than `aaa.log  bbb.log  ccc.log ...`.

This is what I have, which works if I don't include the optional argument:

```
function wls {
    watch "ls $1 | column -c ${COLUMNS}"
}
```

How do I stop bash from evaluating the wildcard to soon, so the wildcard is passed intact as an argument for ls?

I have tried changing the double quotes to singles, and encasing ls $1 in single quotes.

Comment: That's how wildcards work in the shell. Most programs don't have their own wildcard expansion code, they rely on the shell to expand the arguments before passing them.

Comment: You have to quote the argument to prevent expansion: `wls "*.log"`

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, using quotes around the argument is a workaround. It would still be neater if I found a way without having to quote it, like how normal `ls *.log` works.

Comment: Sorry, it's not possible. The shell *always* expands unquoted wildcards.

Comment: Normal `ls *.log` works by the shell expanding the wildcard first.

Comment: @PeteSmyth I don't know what you have against quoting, but the only way to avoid it is to disable globbing altogether with `set -o noglob`, which you probably don't want. They say [it's bad to parse ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) anyway, so consider implementing your function using `find` instead.

Comment: @Verpous The traditional wisdom against parsing ls doesn't really apply here. OP seems to be doing exactly what ls is intended for - displaying a list of files to the user (while periodically refreshing it with watch).